# use INotifyRead with ExcelNPOIStorage

Tags: filehelpers

I'am using ExcelNPOIStorage but I need to implement INotifyRead, but this is not working.

This is the class:

```
public class User : INotifyRead
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;

    public void AfterRead(AfterReadEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public void BeforeRead(BeforeReadEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

This is how I use ExcelNPOIStorage:

```
var provider = new ExcelNPOIStorage(typeof(User))
{
    StartRow = 0,
    StartColumn = 0,
    FileName = pathToFile,
    SheetName = "Users"
};

provider.ErrorManager.ErrorMode = ErrorMode.SaveAndContinue;

var res = (User[])provider.ExtractRecords();
```

But never do 'BeforeRead', additinally I cannot use Optional parameter like this: `[FieldOptional]`

Do I need to do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExcelStorageBase which is inherited by ExcelNPOIStorage does not implement the filehelper INotify interfaces.  In fact, it doesn't implement the older BeforeRecord/AfterRecord events either according to the code online.